# Set something (a setting, variable, piece of configuration) to/at/for a specific value - programming and IT

Tags: prepositions, programming

During a code review, I noticed a phrasing in an error message that made me scratch my head a little. The message was something akin to:

> *The value is set for {}*

where `{}` is a place-holder for a numeric or text value.

Somehow, it feels a bit off to me and personally, I'd go for

> *The value is set **to** {}*

but that's just my instinct and I don't know a grammar rule to back it up.

Which (if any) of these two prepositions can be used in this context? *For* or *to*?

The [entry for the word *set* [VERB] in the Macmillan English Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/set_1) mentions the context of device settings, which is a bit similar, as the line mentioned above pertains to a piece of software configuration.

> 3
>
> ...
>
> > a.
> >     to change the time on a clock or the controls on a piece of equipment
>
> *Can you help me **set** the VCR?*
>
> **set** something **at** something: ***Set** the thermostat **at** 68 degrees.*
>
> **set** something **for** something: *I’m **setting** the alarm **for** 6.30.*

with no mention of *to* being used as the preposition.

I also found this [thread on *Quora*](https://www.quora.com/English-as-a-Foreign-Language/Is-it-grammatically-correct-Set-it-to-true), in which the OP is recommended to use the same phrasing I'd pick.

The stormtrooper in this [opening scene of *Star Wars*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lm_YBE1e8O0), on the other hand, seems to prefer to set his weapon *for* stun.

Which is the most correct preposition one could use in this context and which one feels most natural?

*Set the value to 3* / *Set the value for 3* / *Set the value at 3*

Brownie points for pointing to a credible (even more so than Star Wars!) source.

Comment: You only ***set** something **for** an **outcome***, which is why *Set the alarm for 6:30, Set phasers for stun, Set a course for home* are all credible. But in most contexts we use ***to*** anyway (all of those examples *could* reasonably use ***to*** instead), so if you're not sure just stick with that.

Comment: If it's reporting the state of the variable I'd say "the value **is**".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *for* option is incorrect in this context. In programming you set a value for the left-hand side, not the right-hand side. For instance, one could say "I set the configuration for the User class in user.json."  In the offending statement, the most parsimonious phrasing is "x is set to {}", which is less wordy than the redundant "the value of x is set to {}". *Set to* is the English equivalent of JavaScript/Python/Java/C/C+* assignment operator =.